# ProgresDialog does not dismiss onPostExecute when called other function twice

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a AsyncTask that gets response from server. When I get the response I update the database by calling a function from another class.

```
dbHandler = new DbHandler(getApplicationContext());

new updateDb().execute("ZON", "obtenerCSVzonas");---first call to AsyncTask

new updateDb().execute("CLI", "obtenerCSVclientes");---second call to AsyncTask



@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            if (update == zoneList)
                dbHandler.CreateZoneEntry(resultString);

            else if (update == custList)
                dbHandler.CreateCustEntry(resultString);

            progDailog.dismiss();

        }
```

here onPostexecute method calls the functions for updating database.

My problem is that even when the function is finished the progressDialog still shows. It does not dismiss.

**Declare**

```
public class SelectionMenu extends Activity {

    TextView SelectionHeader;
    ImageButton ShoppingList;
    ImageButton Clients;

    String uid;
    String pass;

    ProgressDialog progDailog;
```

**Initialise**

```
private class updateDb extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            jsn = new JSONObject();
            header = new JSONObject();

            para = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            progDailog = new ProgressDialog(SelectionMenu.this);
            progDailog.setMessage("UPDATING DATABASE");
            progDailog.show();
        }
```

Comment: Please post code where you create declare variable progDialog and where you initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your `Progress Dialog` before your first task and dismiss it after your second task

Comment: I dismiss it after each task and then call Asynctask again with second tasks parameter

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do it that way

Comment: Yes so that I can reuse the same code. This way I call the AsyncTask with different parameters and update the Database

Comment: `progDailog.start();

new updateDb().execute("ZON", "obtenerCSVzonas");---first call to AsyncTask

new updateDb().execute("CLI", "obtenerCSVclientes");---second call to AsyncTask

progDailog.dismiss();`

That should work

Comment: Worked like charm ! Thanks.  Can you explain me what was that magic ?

Comment: Just start progress dialog, do your processing or any functions once you are done, stop it.

Comment: Wasnt I doing the same initially ?

Comment: Logically you are doing the same thing. Best practice, don't call the same line of code multiple times